# Querying BigQuery tables from Cloud SQL

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-sql

I have a big table in Google BigQuery and I want to query it from Google Cloud SQL (fetch data from GBQ tables). Is there any way to do this?

Comment: You cannot query the data directly, but you can download the data in CSV format from BigQuery and import it into a Cloud SQL database.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible. You can export your table into GCS, and then load into Cloud SQL.